# How can replace the eval function with other method in the ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, eval

I have read some material ,it says that eval is evil ,eval can be replaced wit some method.
The code snippet below can call sinajs stock price api,when you type some company's ticker in `input` ,its price will show in console.log's window,for example to input `600020`.

```js
 

function stock(){
    ticker = $("#code").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh" + ticker,
        dataType : "script",
        cache : "false",
        timeout : 2000,
        success : function(data) {
            sname = eval("hq_str_sh" + ticker);
            console.log(sname);},
        error : function() {alert("wrong");}
    });
}
```

```html
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    tiker:
    <input id="code" type="text" size="10">
    <input id="Search" type="button" onclick="stock()" value="query">
```

How to replace the eval function with some method for the below code snippet?

```
success : function(data) {
    sname = eval("hq_str_sh" + ticker);
    console.log(sname);},
```

It's my try:

```
success : function(data) {
    window["myTicker"] = "hq_str_sh" + ticker;
    console.log(myTicker);},
```

Failed.

Comment: what does `console.log(window["hq_str_sh" + ticker])` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

console.log(window["hq_str_sh" + ticker])

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the response.

```
data.substring(4, c.length - 1).split("=")[1];
```

That will be the response past the var part without the trailing ;, split it on the = sign and the data is the second element of the array.